# Creat a fixed of frame ToolBar,and add two barItem in the ToolBar,but one of barItems overrun iPhone'screen when app run in iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitoolbar

I write code to add a toolbar,and add two barItem in this, but "Done" button is overrun the iPhone'screen,I can't understand what happened.
[image: Code]

[image: iPhone]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a specific width number try this.

```
Toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
```